# Bash can't find right directory in script

Tags: python, bash, cd

I'm making a compress script for my text editor, and it's all working up to the part where it needs to make the file `Run`. Inside of Run is just this code: `python ./App.pyc`. When I run the program by double-clicking on it in Finder, it says that it `can't open file './App.pyc' [Errno 2] No such file or directory` within Terminal.

And if I run it through Terminal after I've `cd`'d to the directory `Run` and `App.pyc` are in, it works. I'm assuming this is because we aren't in the right directory.

My question is, how can I make sure `Run` is being ran in the right directory? If I put `cd` in it, it'll work, but then if somebody moves the folder elsewhere it won't work anymore.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python

### Compresser script.

# Compress files.
import App
import Colors

# Import modules
import os

# Clear the folder to put the compressed
# files in (if it exists).
try:
    os.system('rm -rf BasicEdit\ Compressed')
except:
    pass

# Remake the folder to put compressed files in.
os.system('mkdir BasicEdit\ Compressed')

# Move the compiled files into the BasicEdit
# Compressed folder.
os.system('mv App.pyc BasicEdit\ Compressed/')
os.system('mv Colors.pyc BasicEdit\ Compressed/')

# Create contents of run file.
run_file_contents = "python ./App.pyc\n"

# Write run file.
run_file = open("./BasicEdit Compressed/Run", 'w')
run_file.write(run_file_contents)

# Give permissions of run file to anybody.
os.system('chmod a+x ./BasicEdit\ Compressed/Run')

# Finally compress BasicEdit, and remove the old
# folder for BasicEdit Compressed.
os.system('zip -9r BasicEdit.zip BasicEdit\ Compressed')
os.system('rm -rf BasicEdit\ Compressed')
```

(PS, what's `[Errno 1]`? I've never seen it before.)

Comment: can you post your script code please?

Comment: Sure, I'll add the compress script.

Comment: Use a full path instead of a relative path.

Comment: "Errno 2" is referring to the fact that the internal variable `errno` was assigned a value of 2 by `fopen`.  It is a convention by which the called function communicates the reason for the failure to the caller.  It is redundant in the error message and really should not be there.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, I can't use the full path because then if somebody moves the file to, say, they're Applications folder, it won't work anymore.

Comment: You could get the absolute path by `pwd` in bash or `os.pwd()` in python...

Comment: @AquatheSeaWing it doesn't work now!  Put the file in a fixed place and use that path.  Or put it in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` (or somewhere likely to be on each user's PATH) just use the basename.

Comment: @jkalden Ah, perfect! Figured it out. :) Thanks.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so people will find the solution!

Comment: @jkalden, ...but that's the *current* working directory, not the *script's* directory -- if the current working directory were right, this bug wouldn't exist at all!

Comment: agreed! I'm with @Charles Duffy's answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python script's current working directory can be modified with the `os.chdir()` call, after which references to `.` will be correct.

If you want to find the location of the source file currently being run rather than hardcoding a directory, you can use:

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

---

The bash equivalent to this logic is:

```
cd "${BASH_SOURCE%/*}" || {
  echo "Unable to change directory to ${BASH_SOURCE%/*}" >&2
  exit 1
}
```

See [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) for more details and caveats.

Comment: Which would probably work, but I'm trying to make a Bash script, not a Python script. :P

Comment: Why are you posting only a Python script in your question if you want help with bash?

Comment: Because I'm using the Python script to **make** the standalone Bash file.

Comment: Very well; bash version of that logic added.

Comment: Note that for this to work reliably, your script needs to start with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`, as it relies on bash-only extensions.

Comment: And okay, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

<s>As developed above together with @William Purcell, you have to retrieve the absolute path by `os.pwd()` and then use the absolute path for the python call.</s>

I withdraw my proposal and go with @Charles Duffy's answer. However, I don't delete my attempt as the comments seem to be useful to others!

Comment: Well, still not working:
`OUTPUT = "$(pwd)"`


`echo "dir = ${OUTPUT}"`


`echo "run = ${OUTPUT}/Run"`


`python "${OUTPUT}/Run"`


But that makes:


`dir = /Users/towerofnix`


`run = /Users/towerofnix/Run`

`(Can't find directory)`

Comment: @AquatheSeaWing, FYI, it's much more efficient to run `output=$PWD` rather than `output=$(pwd)` in bash. Also, consider using lower-case variable names for things which are neither built-ins or environment variables -- that way you don't overwrite a builtin or an environment variable by mistake.